Using a custom Subscription Key Header when Linking Static Web App backend to API Management
Background
I have:

An API deployed to an Azure API Management instance (APIM)
A Web App deployed to an Azure Static Web App instance (SWA)

In my SWA I have linked the APIM instance as the SWA's backend and I can see that everything works as expected, with the default settings.
However, in my APIM instance, I have a number of other APIs that use a non-default Subscription header name. In these other APIs I prefer to use the Subscription header name x-api-key rather than the default Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header name.
I would like the API used by my SWA to align with all my other APIs and use the same x-api-key header for the Subscription Key.

Problem
I'm finding that when I change the Subscription Header name for my SWA API, suddenly my SWA fails to authenticate with the following error:
Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API. 

With tracing enabled in APIM, I can see that the SWA appears to be passing the correct subscription key value within the default Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header.
I've tried unlinking & relinking the backend, which doesn't appear to resolve the issue.
I've also attempted to write an inbound processing policy to map the Ocp-Apim-Subcription-Key header value into the x-api-key header, which doesn't appear to resolve the issue either...?

Example Screenshots
API Management Configuration

Application Insights Log
The following request was initiated from my SWA frontend.
The SWA calls the getConfiguration operation, using the SWA-proxied url:
https://my-swa-host.azurestaticapps.net/api/home/v1/configuration

Adding the subscription key to the proxied request is managed by the SWA instance itself. As you can see, the default Ocp-Apim-Subcription-Key is being passed to the backend, and the request fails.


Question:

Can a Static Web App use an API Management backend with a non-default Subscription header name?
How do you configure this...?


You need to make the below changes to the API which you have added to the static web app product in APIM.

When you will invoke the static web app endpoint, you need to explicitly pass the x-api-key  in header as shown below-

When I tested an operation in the API which is added in static web app, I can see the header name is being passed as x-api-key in trace.

In this way, you can use a custom subscription key as a header name.
You can also add the below policy in the operation to avoid passing the custom subscription header name explicitly.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 401 && context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"))">
                <send-request mode="copy" response-variable-name="response">
                    <set-url>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString())</set-url>
                    <set-method>GET</set-method>
                    <set-header name="x-api-key" exists-action="override">
                        <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"))</value>
                    </set-header>
                </send-request>
                <return-response response-variable-name="response" />
            </when>
            <otherwise />
        </choose>
    </on-error>
</policies>


Firstly, thank you for your answer. I consider adding the x-api-key explicitly to all calls made to the SWA an unacceptable compromise.
If you trace this, you'll see Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key is automatically added and managed by the SWA. If you navigate to the frontend of your SWA it will be broken - and including it from the frontend calls is no

@Stevie When I test the API associated with SWA product, I can't see Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key in trace post updating it to x-api-key in settings

That may be true from Postman, however if your SWA has a frontend that calls the API - do you see the same thing? The only reason I ask is because I have precisely the same configuration you outline above and in my case it does not work.

@Stevie Can you share some screenshots of how you are invoking it and where you are seeing the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key?

The APIM endpoint is invoked from the SWA frontend. The SWA service should automatically include the subscription's primary key and a valid access token when proxying request to the API management sevice, as-per the documentation. I've updated my question to include a few screenshots.

Have you tried to pass the value of x-api-key while making request to https://my-swa-host.azurestaticapps.net/api/home/v1/configuration, are you getting same error?

I have no doubts that would work, however passing the x-api-key from the frontend exposes the subscription primary key in an unsafe way. It should be treated as a secret and managed by the SWA resource.

@Stevie I have added one policy in my answer, please check
